# How do you write an event handler for when a Firebase database trigger sends data back?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I've written a Cloud Function that returns the new data that is the result of writing to a Firebase Database:

```
exports.getUpdate = functions.database.ref('<a name>')
    .onWrite(<function>);
```

What do I write Java-side to listen for and get the data returned by `getUpdate`?

I tried

```
        FirebaseFunctions.getInstance()
            .getHttpsCallable("getUpdate")
            .call(<arguments to getUpdate>)
            .addOnCompleteListener(<a method>);
```

but this just gives back Unauthorized.

Answer (score 1):

Your function defines a database trigger:

```
exports.getUpdate = functions.database.ref('<a name>')
    .onWrite(<function>);
```

Triggers don't "return" anything.  They can't be invoked directly from a client app.  They just respond to database events (changes being made to the database).  In your case, it's a write to Realtime Database at the given `ref`.

The client code you've written depends there being a [callable function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) to invoke.  Database triggers are not "callable".   If you want to invoke code directly from a web or mobile client, you will have to implement a callable function as show in the linked documentation.